# Get facebook data as list (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, facebook-graph-api

*this uses a python wrapper to access facebook's graph API

So, I am trying to get a list of document IDs in a facebook group
I am able to get the ids, but they come in as a 2-item dictionary.
All of the ids are on one of the dictionary items in this format:

```
u'data':[{u'id': u'11111111111111'}, {u'id': u'22222222222}....]
```

and so on

Is there a way to either
a) have the data come in as a list and not a dictionary
b) convert this dictionary item into a list of IDs

code...

```
graph=facebook.GraphAPI(token)
IdDict = graph.get_object("xxNameOfGroupxx/docs", fields='id')
print type(idDict)
print len(idDict)
```

---

```
<type 'dict'>
2
```

Comment: You can just pull the `id` out and make a list out of it...

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []
b= {1:'one', 2:'two}
a.append(b.copy())
print(a) --> [{1: 'one', 2: 'two'}]
print(type(a)) --> <class 'list'>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code snippets to make it more understandable for the person asking the question.